# Username and Timestamp when a cell is edited in Google Sheets using Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, timestamp

I'm trying to write a script to achieve the following:

Let's say in google sheets data is entered in Col K. I would like Col L to give me the username of the person who entered the data and Col M to show me when the data was entered with a timestamp. Further, if Col K is updated later on in the future, i want Col L and M to remain as is but Col N to show username of the person updated Col K and Col O to show the timestamp when the user updated Col K.

I wrote a script (see below) which seems to be working fine on the columns K,L,M,N,O however when I change the script to work for columns to F, G, H, I, J I get the timestamps in columns H and J but I don't get the usernames in Col G and I which seems odd. Could someone see what is the issue here?

```
function onEdit(event) {
  var name = event.range.getSheet().getName();
  switch (name) {
    case "AA":
      update(event)
      break;
  }
}


function update(event){

  var ColK = 11;  // Column Number of "K"

  var changedRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  if (changedRange.getColumn() == ColK) {
  if (changedRange.getRowIndex() >=7 ) {
    // An edit has occurred in Column J
    var state = changedRange.getValue();
    var adjacentDate = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("AA").getRange(changedRange.getRow(),ColK+4);
    var adjacentDate2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("AA").getRange(changedRange.getRow(),ColK+2);
    var adjacentLDAP = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("AA").getRange(changedRange.getRow(),ColK+3);
    var adjacentLDAP2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("AA").getRange(changedRange.getRow(),ColK+1);
    var timestamp = new Date(); // Get the current time

    adjacentDate2.setValue(timestamp);
    adjacentLDAP2.setValue(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail());

    if (adjacentDate.getValue() == "") {

        // Write timestamp into adjacent cell
        adjacentDate.setValue(timestamp);
        adjacentLDAP.setValue(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail());
    }
  }
    }
}
```

Comment: Couldn't the same cell be edited dozens of times? This seems to be a very inefficient way of doing things, no? Why not just append the names and timestamps comma separated all in the same two columns?

Comment: Yeah i just want to see when the original data was input and when the data was last changed. I don't need the timestamp for every time the data changes. Plus i need to calculate the dates between last update and original query as well so putting a comma and separating them in the same column wont work for me.

Comment: I changed getActiveUser to getEffectiveUser and the code works now !

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use something like this as you may have multiple edits and you could very easily run out of columns. Then you can use a simple formula to extract the first or last edit if needed easily visible.

```
var triggerSheet = "AA"; //trigger sheet
var triggerRow = 7; //trigger row
var ColK = 11;  // trigger column
var ColL = 12;  // comma seperated users
var ColM = 13;  // comma seperated time stamps

function onEdit(event) {
  var name = event.range.getSheet().getName();
  switch (name) {
    case triggerSheet:
      update(event)
      break;
  }
}

function update(event){
  var changedRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  if (changedRange.getColumn() == ColK) {
    if (changedRange.getRowIndex() >=triggerRow ) {
      var state = changedRange.getValue();
      var users = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(triggerSheet).getRange(changedRange.getRow(),ColL);
      var times = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(triggerSheet).getRange(changedRange.getRow(),ColM);
      var timestamp = new Date(); // Get the current time
      var originalUsers = users.getValue();
      var originalTimes = times.getValue();
      times.setValue(originalTimes+timestamp+",");
      users.setValue(originalUsers+Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()+",");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I dont need all the edits. The only relevant timestamps are when the data was originally entered in the cell and when the data was last updated. Those are the only 2 timestamps with username required.

Comment: I tried the above code, and like i said it's giving me timestamps in one cell which is not what i need but thanks for the code though ! I also noticed instead of username it just mentions "," so i assume its not picking up the username for some reason

Comment: @user12333294 if it returns blank that is a security issue with however you have the sheet set up "If security policies do not allow access to the user's identity, User.getEmail() returns a blank string." also if you only return the first and last edit that won't be very useful because someone can accidentally hit enter on a cell below to delete the last edit... but you are saying you really want first created and last modified columns? By recording all changes you can easily extract that from this history column if you can get your security issues fixed.